# MSP430: unable to find device a device matching 0451:f432

Tags: msp430

everyone!
My problem is when I use the command 'lsusb', The result is:
Bus 002 Device 011: ID 0451:2046 Texas Instruments, Inc. TUSB2046 Hub
Bus 002 Device 012: ID 2047:0013 Texas Instruments

But when I use 'make msp5529 install', it shows:
usbutil: unable to find a device matching 0451:f432
make: *** [program] Error 255

I don't know how can I transform '0451:f432' to '0451:2046'. I tried add an rule in /etc/udev/rules.d/82-msp430.rules like '

SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0451", ATTRS{idProduct}=="2046", MODE="0666", GROUP="users".'

But it still shows the same error. Do you know why? Thank you very much!!  :)

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're playing with the msp430F5529 Launchpad, in which case the `0451:f432` VID/PID won't work. In summary, you'll need to run:

```
sudo mspdebug tilib "prog bin.elf"
```

where `bin.elf` is the binary program that you generated. I found that the easiest way to get a working mspdebug with tilib is downloading the Energia IDE for msp430.